# how do you shrink a form block?

Tags: html, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FleJ3.png)
I want to make my form block smaller so then I can have my navigation buttons on the size

```
        <form>
         <legend><h1>login</h1></legend>
         user: <input id="Email" type="email" class="user">
         <br>
         password: <input id="password" type="password" class="pass"> 
         <br>   
         <button class="submit">Login</button>
         <nav>
            <a href="SignUpPage.HTML" class="signUpPage_link">Dont have an account?</a>
         </nav>
        </form>
```

I tried changing the margin:

```
    margin: 0 300px 0 300px;
```

and I tried charging the padding:

```
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 400px;
```

however that only changed the size of the border and not the block itself

Comment: You should perhaps use a grid layout in this case.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducable codepen?

Answer (score 0):

You have to style the `input`

```
input {
  width: 1%;
  height: 1%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I used this code however it only shrank the border and not the actual block itself (margin). The reason I want to shrink the block is so that I can place my navigation section next to the main content but thank you for answering my question as it has helped me learn another way to size borders

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make the login section smaller? So you can have a nav bar on side?

```
<div style="width: 175px; height: 200px; border-width: 1px,black;border-style: solid;">
<form  >
    <legend><h2 style="text-align: center;">Login</h2></legend>
    user: <input id="Email" type="email" class="user">
    <br>
    password: <input id="password" type="password" class="pass"> 
    <br>   
    <button class="submit">Login</button>
    <nav>
       <a href="SignUpPage.HTML" class="signUpPage_link">Dont have an account?</a>
    </nav>
   </form>
   </div>
```

See if this helps? You might look into flexbox vs and grid, see if that will is what you are trying to achieve. Also look up css styling and how padding and margins affect the layout of your webpage.